# textarea turns transparent when adding background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, textarea, transparent

Im trying to add a background image to my `textarea` - but the following code just makes it transparent. The path and image is valid

```
var input = $("<textarea>");

            $(input).css({ background: 'url("Images/leviathan.jpg")'});

            item.append(input);
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You Want to change One Css Properties Use this one
 Change Background to Background-iamge

```
     var input = $("<textarea>");     
$(input).css( 'background-image' , 'url(../Images/leviathan.jpg)');
```